# Windows Command Prompt set character size

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, command-prompt

There is a command to set the command prompt character size to 10x18? And.. Can I do this in a python script probably using `os.system()` function?

[image: Screenshot of the gui settings]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the command prompt :

```
import os
os.system("mode con cols=18 lines=10") # cols for the width and lines for the length
```

To change the charachter size of the command prompt :

```
import ctypes

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 12
font.dwFontSize.X = 10  # in your case X=10
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18  # and Y=18



handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle,False, ctypes.byref(font))
```

Comment: That sets the cols and lines of the window not of the characters

Comment: Why overwrite the OP's `FontFamily` and `FontWeight`? For example the low 4 bits of `FontFamily` (54 & 0xf == 6) indicate a TrueType, fixed-pitch font. The upper 4 bits (48) signify a "Modern" font family. You seem steadfast in avoiding calling `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx` for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Setting the values to 0 is just using whatever the current value is for the arbitrary font index 12. That's still wrong.

Comment: The console maintains a list of font records (probably it's a linked list), one of which is the current record. This function both updates a record at the given `nFont` index and sets it as the current font. What the OP needs is to just modify the `dwFontSize` of the current font record, which you can get by calling `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(handle, False, ctypes.byref(font))`.